# How to use this code swift achieve? hide dock icon set

Tags: swift

Add badge

```
[[NSApp dockTile] setBadgeLabel:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", random() % 11]];
[NSApp setActivationPolicy: NSApplicationActivationPolicyProhibited];
```

How to use this code swift achieve?

Comment: what is your question? what have you even tried? do you have any problem with understanding the _Swift_ languages's syntax, perhaps?

Comment: You seem to be lacking basic understanding of the swift language. Please read Apple's Documentation...

Comment: I did not learn a programming language, based on examples of written procedures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
let doc =  NSApp.dockTile as NSDockTile
doc.badgeLabel = NSString(format: "%d", random() % 11)
NSApp.setActivationPolicy(.Prohibited)
```

Comment: `NSApp.setActivationPolicy(NSApplicationActivationPolicy.Prohibited)`This can eh